# fastest way to find unique pairs in a 2d vector

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, find, unique

I'm looking for an efficient and fast algorithm to find the unique pairs in a 2d vector. 
For example:
vec=[[1 5] [2 2] [1 5] [3 1] [6 3] [2 2]]
I want to generate the 2d vector below which only have the unique pairs.
vec=[[1 5] [2 2] [3 1] [6 3]]

Demonstration with a pseudo-code (or any C like syntax) will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: If you are looking for a c-style syntax, why don't you tag that language in yout post?

Comment: And what have you done in pursuit of an answer other than post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how fast algorithm are you looking for but NlogN + N algorithm idea

```
//create an extra vector, we call it sol
vec = [[1 5], [2 2], [1 5], [3 1], [6 3], [2 2]]
sort(vec)    
i = 0
while i < vec.length()
    sol.push_back(i)
    i = i + 1
    while i < vec.length() and vec[i] == vec[i-1]
        i = i + 1
```

sol is the vector that you want

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solved in O(n), best is O(n) and worst is o(2n)

Answer (score 0):

python you just go:

```
set([(1,2), (2,3),(1,2)]
```

in C++, you could use and `unordered set`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/

using `pair<int,int>` for your points

Answer (score 0):

This is an O(n log n) time in place solution.

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
auto new_size = unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - vec.begin();
vec.resize(new_size);
```